# Compiled program cannot find a library

Tags: linux, prolog, swi-prolog

First of all: I'm a total newbie.
I have a compiled program that raises this error:

```
ERROR: pl2xpce: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: Failed to initialise the XPCE tookit.  This is normally
ERROR: caused by a missing or incompatible X11 library.
ERROR: See http://www.swi-prolog.org/build/issues/xpce.html
ERROR: Sorry, cannot recover from this.  Process terminates.
```

I have read [here](https://lists.iai.uni-bonn.de/pipermail/swi-prolog/2008/000432.html) that maybe the library is placed somewhere out the *foreign* search path. My library is placed in `/usr/lib/swi-prolog/lib/amd64/pl2xpce.so`. So, my questions:

- how can I check which is the *foreign* path?
- how can I make my program find this library?

I'm on an Ubuntu 13.10 machine with the development version of SWI Prolog.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I posted the very same question on the [SWI-Prolog mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swi-prolog/hhNBuNvXbfE) and following their advice I just switched back to the *stable* version. Everything seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Normally the library path is configured under the /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ directory, 
   On my machine, the /etc/ld.so.conf file contains all .conf file under that directory

   ➜  data-analyse git:(master) cat /etc/ld.so.conf

   include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
2. So you can just create another conf file under /etc/ld.so.conf.d/(for example 
   prolog.conf which contains the path to the prolog library) and then run the 
   `sudo ldconfig` command to update the ld path